# Need a help in Query to check whether Task is completed by other user or not

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables in database Task, User & assignedTo.

Task contains information of Task created by Admin, User is list of User & assignedTo contains information about which task assign to which user.

i need to query on 'assignedTo' table to show a list of Task assigned to users on their Dashboard. Problem is a single Task is assigned to multiple user and it may possible task may be completed by one of them. So i need to show task which are in Open Status and not completed by anyone in assigned list.
Below is structure of 'assignedTo' Table:

```
--------------------------------
| id | taskId | userId | status|
--------------------------------
| 1  |  1     | 1      | open  |  
| 2  |  1     | 2      | open  |
| 3  |  1     | 3      | open  |
| 4  |  1     | 4      | open  |
| 5  |  2     | 1      | open  |
| 6  |  2     | 2      | close |
| 7  |  3     | 1      | open  |
| 8  |  3     | 2      | open  |
--------------------------------
```

So as per above data, Task 1 is shown on user 1,2,3 & 4 Dashboard as it is not closed by any of them.
Task 2 is shown on no one's Dash as it is closed by User 2.
Similarly, Task 3 is shown on user 1 & 2 Dash as it is open for both of them.

i tried to join same table to it's own but failed to execute.

```
SELECT * FROM assignedTo as a1
JOIN assignedTo as a2 ON a2.taskId = a1.taskId AND a2.userId != 1 AND a2.status == 'open' 
WHERE a1.userId = 1 AND a1.status = 'open'
```

Please help with Query if possible.

Comment: So one task can be assigned to multiple users?

Answer (score 2):

You can use not in and subselect

```
select * 
from  assignedTo 
where taskid not in (select distinct taskid 
                      from assignedTo 
                       where status = 'close');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM assignedTo a1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM assignedTo a2
    WHERE
        a2.taskId = a1.taskId
        AND a2.status = 'close'
)
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9bc6dc/1/0)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use an OUTER JOIN...

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM assignedTo x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN assignedTo y 
    ON y.taskid = x.taskid 
   AND y.status = 'close' 
 WHERE y.id IS NULL;
```